# BI Publisher and Reporting

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher, oracle-ccb

I am having an issue viewing my report properly in a third party application called Oracle CC&B. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBJaH.jpg)

It seems to be displaying a blank page or something above my report as I can see two scrollbars. I have no blank page within the layout of BI Publisher. Perhaps, there is something done wrong in BI Publisher?

Comment: please revise your question. You seem to have a typo that makes the question unclear: "I have to blank page within..."

Comment: @cdabel is this better? Can anyone assist?